# When should release versions be bumped?

Tags: continuous-integration, versioning, semantic-versioning

I want my projects to be [SemVer](https://semver.org/) compliant. I follow a [trunk-based development](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/) approach. I also want to keep things as simple as possible.

I assume that each commit on `main` (default branch) is a possible release candidate. So my CI/CD pipeline looks at the `M.m.p` version number in the codebase, and build & release artefacts (e.g. npm/Python packages, Docker images) with a `M.m.p.rc<commit_sha>` tag (e.g. `3.2.0.rc7e97e56`).

A “release” is simply a commit on `main` which has been tagged (patch versions dealt with [a bit differently](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/branch-for-release/#late-creation-of-release-branches)). The changelog should be updated only once per release.

**Question:** When should the `M.m.p` version be bumped? On releases, or right after?

<sub>My ulterior motivation is to have it eventually all automated via [`release-it`](https://github.com/release-it/release-it)</sub>.

##### Approach 1: Bump on release commits

A release consists in one single commit that updates the changelog and bump the version to the value of the version/tag (example [here](https://github.com/release-it/release-it/commit/efd7872270fa17a1844acef6fea10baaa781015e)).

[image]

- pros: one single commit to bump version + release.
- cons: “release candidate” versions don't make much sense, as `0.1.0.rc1` happens *after* `0.1.0` has been released. (That's a blocker for me.)

##### Approach 2:  Bump right after release

Right after a release, add a new tag which bumps the default version on `main`. Release commit is simply about updating the changelog.

[image]

- pros: “.rc” versions now make sense,
- cons: a lot of extra clutter commits.

##### Approach 3: *Set* version on release commits

In this approach, the version in `main` remains `0.0.0` and releases are done on specific branches, where the release commits update the changelog and *set* the version to the correct value (example [here](https://github.com/apache/superset/commit/eb42fa7a2e21d5d4d69a6e8a9787dc8ea1dd6348)).

[image]

<sub>(note that the picture is misleading, as it doesn't show the separate branch.)</sub>

- pros: one-commit release,
- cons: un-informative version number for `main`'s “.rc” builds.

Comment: Note that my policy is that anything released from `main`, no matter how small the change is, is a `minor` release. (Patch releases are only in case I want to keep supporting a non-latest version and apply a hotfix to it — so not pure SemVer after all.) So it's easy to know what version to bump in the “bump-only commits”: it's `M.m+1.0` on `main` and `M.m.p+1` on release branches.

Comment: Where is this version number stored? In a config file? Is this file tracked in version control?

Comment: Why do you need release candidate versions?   It seems simpler just to version everything from main/trunk using the same format (without `rc` in the version) and then use a separate 'publish' step to only promote those versions which you want shipped upto the production artefact registry.    (Typically involves using another separate private/internal registry for all the artefacts produced by the CI/build process, to make those available internally).

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes, the version is stored in `.toml` or `.json` files, tracked in the repo.

Comment: @BenCottrell I need to release artifacts for my integration test (run via GitHub actions — which triggers a Nextflow run, which imports from the artifact registry). Artifacts consist of Docker images and Python packages. “Release candidate” is what makes the most sense (IMHO) in this context (where “dev” are for commits on feature branches/PRs) — but they could be tagged anyhow. They need to be published to the artifact registry, though. More than happy to be shown another way to approach this.

Comment: @ebosi - my suggestion would be to use a different internal, private registry for internal matters such as testing.   That removes versioning from the release process and makes it solely a build concern.  The release process can just be about publishing to the external registries instead

Comment: @BenCottrell having two registries would help indeed… but my question is then: how to name (or “tag”) the dev/rc version of the artifacts?

Comment: @ebosi You should be able to remove release information from your version scheme entirely.  Using 'release status' such as `rc` in a version is often problematic because versions are usually chosen automatically at build time, whereas a decision to release is often a manual human step that happens later.   By not using `rc` or some other name/tag in the version, the release process can be entirely separate, perhaps as simple as copying the artefact into the production registry, without altering its name or version.    _(A `dev` tag for feature branch builds is a good idea however)_

Comment: I think there's missing information from the question.

> I want my projects to be SemVer compliant.

Why? What problem(s) are you trying to solve with SemVer? And specifically who is the audience for the version number? Which people or systems are you expecting to read the version numbers you put on your projects and use them to help make decisions. If there are none, then there's perhaps no point doing SemVer.

Comment: Are these projects libraries or applications? SemVer is mostly relevant for libraries. It could also apply where a 3rd party will install the product and then use it via an API. It has little relevance to products you only install in-house or that do not have APIs.

Answer (score 3):

When I think about this the first thing that comes to mind when I think about your question, is that the version should be bumped according to specific rules. and this is pretty much the way I do it and still follow SemVer:

- Major Version (M): Increment the major version when you make incompatible changes to the public API or introduce significant new features. This indicates that the new version may not be backward compatible with previous versions.
- Minor Version (m): Increment the minor version when you add functionality in a backward-compatible manner. This means that the new version introduces new
  features or enhancements but does not break existing functionality.
- Patch Version (p): Increment the patch version when you make backward-compatible bug fixes or patches. This means that the new version addresses issues or fixes bugs without introducing new features or breaking existing functionality.

This might not be the best way but from what you described, and this has worked for me, so although you use trunk based, I think this will work for you.  I do each one pretty much immediately after the type of whatever change that I am doing that fit the Mmp context.

Comment: To make sure I understand, right after a PR has been [squash-]merged, you add another commit that bumps the version according to the type of change it was? Or do you change the version in the PR itself?

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it you are doing a few things "wrong"

1. Confusing versions of code and versions of your product

   Versioning code is problematic, I can have concurrent branches, rollbacks, delayed merges etc. Normally you just verison your product, the compiled or packaged code.
2. The "trunk based dev" you link to has release branches and feature branches, but you seem to be trying to get everything to work on a single branch.

If you "released" your product in some way that wasn't just a commit, such as publishing it to an ftp site, or compiling it or something. You would have the opportunity at that stage to set the version number, of the *product* as opposed to the version of the *code* You could then simply note in the release notes that it was built from commit x and not version the code at all.

If you used release branches you could use the initial branch commit to set the version on that branch.

The tools are there for you to solve this, It's your self imposed limits which are causing your problems.